# Knockout IE subscribe issue with int and null initial values

Tags: c#, .net, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Here's a [jsfiddle to demo it](http://jsfiddle.net/vREsC/)...

```
dirtyFlag = function(root) {
    var _isDirty = ko.observable(false);
    root.isFilthy = function() {
        return _isDirty();
    };
    var result = ko.computed(function() {
        if (!_isDirty()) {
            ko.toJS(root);
        }
        return _isDirty();
    });

    result.subscribe(function() {
        if (!_isDirty()) {
            _isDirty(true);
            alert('dirty!');
        }
    });

    return result;
};

var viewModel = {
    dataObject: ko.observable()
};
var data = {
    "UserName": "TheName",
    "UserID": 2,
    "Notes": "Yeah!",
    "email": "booya@test.x"
};

viewModel.dataObject = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
dirtyFlag(viewModel.dataObject);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

If you look at the data model, the UserID is an int, the model has a subscribe on it to set a "dirty" flag when there's a change, and I threw in an alert so you know exactly when it is flagged as such.

Enter the input field that contains the id, don't type, don't change it, just click in next box or tab out of it.

If you visit this fiddle with Firefox, Chrome,etc., well it behaves as you expect, nothing happens.

Now visit it with IE, why does it flag the model as dirty after you leave the UserID field? Same effect only in IE if one of the values are a null instead of an int (change the email to null to see)

In the real scenario I'm using a c# object that has been serialized to js, and that all works 100% fine, until I manually subscribe, and again this only happens in IE (currently running IE9 but tried this under various mode/emulation of older versions)

Any insight would be greatly appreciated....thanks!

Comment: Looking at the code, this is one of the unfortunate side-effects of IE's autocomplete. See [here](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/pull/122) for more information. What's happening is that the changed event is firing as it is being initialized. As for why, I don't really understand enough about the differences between IE vs other browsers so I can't really explain. But this would be why it's only happening on IE and not on other browsers, it's an IE only hack.

Comment: Every input starts out as `propertyChangedFired = true` and therefore updates when you first blur on an input.